# It is not possible to decrypt a message encrypted using the rsa method

Tags: python, pyqt5, rsa, pyside2

I have a code that can encode a message and save them to a file`.txt`, and decode this data.
But when decoding an error occurs, how to solve it?

**main.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from crypto import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5.Qt import *
import rsa


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.setWindowTitle("Automatic OGE verification system ver.00.04.75")

        (self.key_pub, self.key_priv) = rsa.newkeys(512)

        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.information)
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.app_key_task)

    def information(self):
        self.key_crypto = self.lineEdit_13.text()
        self.directory_file_ver = self.lineEdit_14.text()
        self.directory_save = self.lineEdit_15.text()
        self.directory_key = self.lineEdit_16.text()
        self.name_key = self.lineEdit_17.text()

        self.key_task()

    def key_task(self):
        self.number_1 = self.lineEdit.text()
        self.number_2 = self.lineEdit_2.text()
        self.number_3 = self.lineEdit_3.text()
        self.number_4 = self.lineEdit_4.text()
        self.number_5 = self.lineEdit_5.text()
        self.number_6 = self.lineEdit_6.text()
        self.number_7 = self.lineEdit_7.text()
        self.number_8 = self.lineEdit_8.text()
        self.number_9 = self.lineEdit_9.text()
        self.number_10 = self.lineEdit_10.text()
        self.number_11 = self.lineEdit_11.text()
        self.number_12 = self.lineEdit_12.text()

        self.key_task_crypto()

    def key_task_crypto(self):
        self.number_1_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_1.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_2_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_2.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_3_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_3.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_4_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_4.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_5_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_5.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_6_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_6.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_7_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_7.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_8_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_8.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_9_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_9.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_10_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_10.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_11_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_11.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)
        self.number_12_crypto = rsa.encrypt(self.number_12.encode('utf8'), self.key_pub)

        self.load_key_task_crypto()

    def load_key_task_crypto(self):
        k = [self.number_1_crypto, self.number_2_crypto, self.number_3_crypto, self.number_4_crypto,
             self.number_5_crypto, self.number_6_crypto, self.number_7_crypto, self.number_8_crypto,
             self.number_9_crypto, self.number_10_crypto, self.number_11_crypto, self.number_12_crypto,
             self.key_crypto]

        directory_save_key = self.directory_key + self.name_key + ".txt"

        with open(directory_save_key, "w") as f:
            f.write("\n".join(str(item) for item in k))
    #####################################
    def app_key_task(self):
        directory_file, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, ".", "*.txt")

        print(f'directory_file = {directory_file} <----')

        with open(directory_file, "r", encoding='utf-8') as file:
            print(file)

            self.number_1_decrypto = (file.readline().strip())
            self.number_2_decrypto = file.readline().strip()
            self.number_3_decrypto = file.readline().strip()
            self.number_4_decrypto = file.readline().strip()
            self.number_5_decrypto = file.readline().strip()
            self.number_6_decrypto = file.readline().strip()
            self.number_7_decrypto = file.readline().strip()
            self.number_8_decrypto = file.readline().strip()
            self.number_9_decrypto = file.readline().strip()
            self.number_10_decrypto = file.readline().strip()
            self.number_11_decrypto = file.readline().strip()
            self.number_12_decrypto = file.readline().strip()

            print(f'self.number_1_decrypto = {self.number_1_decrypto}')
            print(f'self.number_2_decrypto = {self.number_2_decrypto}')
            print(f'self.number_3_decrypto = {self.number_3_decrypto}')
            print(f'self.number_4_decrypto = {self.number_4_decrypto}')
            print(f'self.number_5_decrypto = {self.number_5_decrypto}')
            print(f'self.number_6_decrypto = {self.number_6_decrypto}')
            print(f'self.number_7_decrypto = {self.number_7_decrypto}')
            print(f'self.number_8_decrypto = {self.number_8_decrypto}')
            print(f'self.number_9_decrypto = {self.number_9_decrypto}')
            print(f'self.number_10_decrypto= {self.number_10_decrypto}')
            print(f'self.number_11_decrypto= {self.number_11_decrypto}')
            print(f'self.number_12_decrypto= {self.number_12_decrypto}')

            message = rsa.decrypt(self.number_1_decrypto, self.key_priv)
            print(message.decode('utf8'))
    #######################################
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    app.setStyle("Fusion")
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**crypto.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'crypto.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.6
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(640, 514)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_3.setObjectName("tab_3")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.tab_3)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.tab_3)
        self.groupBox.setObjectName("groupBox")
        self.gridLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.groupBox)
        self.gridLayout_4.setObjectName("gridLayout_4")
        self.gridLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout_3.setObjectName("gridLayout_3")
        self.lineEdit_7 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.lineEdit_7.setObjectName("lineEdit_7")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit_7, 6, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_8 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.lineEdit_8.setObjectName("lineEdit_8")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit_8, 7, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_9 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.lineEdit_9.setObjectName("lineEdit_9")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit_9, 8, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_11 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.lineEdit_11.setObjectName("lineEdit_11")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit_11, 10, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit_3, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_5 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.lineEdit_5.setObjectName("lineEdit_5")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit_5, 4, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.lineEdit_4.setObjectName("lineEdit_4")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit_4, 3, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit_2, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_6 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.lineEdit_6.setObjectName("lineEdit_6")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit_6, 5, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_10 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.lineEdit_10.setObjectName("lineEdit_10")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit_10, 9, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_12 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.lineEdit_12.setObjectName("lineEdit_12")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit_12, 11, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_2, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_3, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_4, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_5, 4, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_6, 5, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_7, 6, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_8, 7, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_9, 8, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_10 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_10.setObjectName("label_10")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_10, 9, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_11 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_11.setObjectName("label_11")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_11, 10, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_12 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_12.setObjectName("label_12")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_12, 11, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_4.addLayout(self.gridLayout_3, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.groupBox_2 = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.groupBox)
        self.groupBox_2.setObjectName("groupBox_2")
        self.gridLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.groupBox_2)
        self.gridLayout_5.setObjectName("gridLayout_5")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox_2)
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.pushButton_3, 7, 0, 1, 2)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox_2)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.pushButton_2, 6, 0, 1, 2)
        self.label_19 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox_2)
        self.label_19.setObjectName("label_19")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.label_19, 4, 0, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_14 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox_2)
        self.lineEdit_14.setObjectName("lineEdit_14")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.lineEdit_14, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_17 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox_2)
        self.lineEdit_17.setObjectName("lineEdit_17")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.lineEdit_17, 4, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_14 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox_2)
        self.label_14.setObjectName("label_14")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.label_14, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_15 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox_2)
        self.label_15.setObjectName("label_15")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.label_15, 5, 0, 1, 1)
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.groupBox_2)
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.comboBox, 5, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_15 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox_2)
        self.lineEdit_15.setObjectName("lineEdit_15")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.lineEdit_15, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_16 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox_2)
        self.label_16.setObjectName("label_16")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.label_16, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox_2)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.pushButton, 9, 0, 1, 2)
        self.lineEdit_16 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox_2)
        self.lineEdit_16.setObjectName("lineEdit_16")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.lineEdit_16, 3, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_18 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox_2)
        self.label_18.setObjectName("label_18")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.label_18, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_13 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox_2)
        self.label_13.setObjectName("label_13")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.label_13, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_13 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox_2)
        self.lineEdit_13.setObjectName("lineEdit_13")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.lineEdit_13, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_4.addWidget(self.groupBox_2, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.groupBox, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_3, "")
        self.tab_5 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_5.setObjectName("tab_5")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_5, "")
        self.tab_4 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_4.setObjectName("tab_4")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_4, "")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tabWidget, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_17 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_17.setObjectName("label_17")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_17, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 640, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.tabWidget.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p>Дишифрование файлов</p></body></html>"))
        self.tabWidget.setWhatsThis(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p>Дишифрование</p></body></html>"))
        self.groupBox.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответы на задания ОГЭ с КРАТКИМ ОТВЕТОМ (проверка/настройка ключей с ответами)"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответ на задание №1"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответ на задание №2"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответ на задание №3"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответ на задание №4"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответ на задание №5"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответ на задание №6"))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответ на задание №7"))
        self.label_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответ на задание №8"))
        self.label_9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответ на задание №9"))
        self.label_10.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответ на задание №10"))
        self.label_11.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответ на задание №11"))
        self.label_12.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответ на задание №12"))
        self.groupBox_2.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Общие настройки"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Загрузить ключ с ответами"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Сохранить данные"))
        self.label_19.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Имя файла с ключем ответа"))
        self.label_14.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Директория файлов для \n"
"проверки"))
        self.label_15.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Вывод данных в файл типа"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", ".txt"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", ".csv"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", ".docx"))
        self.label_16.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p>Директория сохранения </p><p>проверенных файлов</p></body></html>"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Дишифровать файлы"))
        self.label_18.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p>Директория файлов с </p><p>ключем ответов</p></body></html>"))
        self.label_13.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ключ шифрования данных"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_3), _translate("MainWindow", "Дешифровка"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_5), _translate("MainWindow", "Настройка заданий"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_4), _translate("MainWindow", "Статистика"))
        self.label_17.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" font-weight:600;\">ВНИМАНИЕ! ДАННАЯ ВЕРСИЯ ПРОГРАММА НАХОДИТСЯ В БЕТА ВЕРСИИ, В НЕЙ МОГУТ ПРИСУДСТВОВАТЬ</span></p><p><span style=\" font-weight:600;\">НЕ РАБОЧИЕ ФУНКЦИИ. ПОЛЬЗУЯСЬ ПРОГРАММОЙ ВЫ СОГЛАШАЕТЕСЬ С ПРАВИЛАМИ ЕЁ ИСПОЛЬЗОВАНИЯ. </span></p><p>(c)Copyrigth by Alexandrov Andrey </p></body></html>"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**error code**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "crypto_log.py", line 107, in app_key_task message = rsa.decrypt(self.number_1_decrypto, self.key_priv)
File "G:\PyCharm\Python_x32\Python_3_8_10\lib\site-packages\rsa\pkcs1.py", line 255, in decrypt encrypted = transform.bytes2int(crypto)
File "G:\PyCharm\Python_x32\Python_3_8_10\lib\site-packages\rsa\transform.py", line 34, in bytes2int return int.from_bytes(raw_bytes, "big", signed=False)
TypeError: cannot convert 'str' object to bytes
```

To get this error, you need to: after starting the program, open a file previously created with encrypted data (if there is no such file, then create it using the `"Save Data"` button), after which this error will appear in `cmd`.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

[`rsa_decrypt()`](https://stuvel.eu/python-rsa-doc/reference.html#rsa.decrypt) expects its first argument to be a bytes object, but the first argument that you passed to it, `self.number_1_decrypto`, is a *string*. You can fix this by changing this first argument from `self.number_1_decrypto` to `self.number_1_decrypto.encode()`. (See here for an explanation of `encode()`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode)

Comment: This method works in one session, that is, if I save a file with answers, and then log in, I will get the same error regardless of availability.encode

Comment: Most likely this is due to the fact that a new key is created every time, but I do not know how to save it.

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3? Or worse, a mix of both?

Comment: I only use python 3

Comment: If by "works in one session", you mean that you can save a file with answers, that probably means that you are not using `app_key_task()` in that session. It's `app_key_task()` that tries to use `rsa.decrypt()` with a string instead of bytes. Are you actually running a line that says `message = rsa.decrypt(self.number_1_decrypto.encode(), self.key_priv)`?

Comment: I mean, I can save the answers and encrypt them, but at the same time open this file the next day, but the file will not open, due to the fact that the key is constantly changing, and I do not know how to save it.

Comment: If you've gotten to the point that you get the error `TypeError: cannot convert 'str' object to bytes`, then you already *have* opened the file, since you were able to extract the string `self.number_1_decrypto` from it. If the problem was the key changing, you'd probably get an error different from the `TypeError` that you got.

Comment: I did not say that I could not open the file, I said that I could not decrypt data from a file created in one time period, and read in another. This error is really related to the incorrect representation of encrypted data, but when this error is eliminated, decryption is not possible, the encryption keys are different.

Comment: @Settings obviously, since you're always using `newkeys()`, the keys are not valid if you restart the program. Read the documentation to know how to save and restore them.

Comment: @musicamante if I understood the examples from the documentation, I wouldn't write here.

Comment: @Settings the problem of your original question is completely different from what you're asking now. We cannot just guess what you know or understand if you're asking different questions. This is not a forum with long threads that can cover multiple aspects. If you don't understand how to store keys between sessions then create a new question about that specific problem and provide an *actual* [mre] (not like you did for this one, which is certainly not minimal) showing an *actual* attempt to solve the problem. Also please review the [tour] and read [ask].